# how to insert image into sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, sql-server-2012

In my project, I should insert images to the database from different types (png, bmp)
I've tried this code:
table name: Fingers
Column name: Image

```
DECLARE @image1    VARBINARY(MAX)

SELECT @image1 = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX))

FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\PNG\1_1.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x

INSERT INTO Fingers (Image)  SELECT  @image1
```

but i receive the following error:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Cannot bulk load because the file
>   "C:\PNG\1_1.png" could not be opened. Operating system error code
>   3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

how to resolve this error?

Comment: This Refers to a path on the database server, and the server process must have read access to the file

Comment: Is there any other method to insert image to database from local disk?@ErikEJ

Comment: This link will give some information:-    stackoverflow.com/q/33962272/153923